# How to add columns to an existing Athena table using Avro storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, avro, amazon-athena

I have an existing Athena table (w/ hive-style partitions) that's using the Avro SerDe. When I first created the table, I declared the Athena schema as well as the Athena `avro.schema.literal` schema per AWS instructions. Everything has been working great.

I now wish to add new columns that will apply going forward but not be present on the old partitions. I tried a basic `ADD COLUMNS` command that claims to succeed but has no impact on `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. I then wondered if I needed to change the Avro schema declaration as well, which I attempted to do but discovered that `ALTER TABLE SET SERDEPROPERTIES` DDL is [not supported in Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unsupported-ddl.html).

AWS claims [I should be able to add columns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html) when using Avro, but at this point I'm unsure how to do it. Even if I'm willing to drop the table metadata and redeclare all of the partitions, I'm not sure how to do it right since the schema is different on the historical partitions.

Looking for high-level guidance on the steps to be taken. Documentation is scant and Athena seems to be lacking support for commands that are referenced in this same scenario in vanilla Hive world. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Are you saying that some files in S3 have the new column, but the 'historical' files do not have the new column? That _probably_ won't work, since Athena assumes that all files have the same schema. You might need to use `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a new table from the historical data, with NULL as the new columns, with the `location` specifying a new location in S3.

Comment: Yes, some avro files will have it and some won't. But, Athena supports differing schemas across partitions (as long as their compatible w/ the table-level schema) - and Athena's own docs say avro tables support adding columns - just not how to do it necessarily.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html

Comment: That's interesting! It does say that Athena can handle different schemas per partition, but it doesn't say what would happen if you try to access a column that doesn't exist in some partitions. Also, I'm unsure if change the DDL will actually impact the stored files -- I have always assumed that Athena will never change the content of any files unless it is using `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a _new_ table. Let us know what you discover!